# Unable to return objects within an object.keys foreach loop that don't match the string.prototype.replace method

Tags: javascript, foreach, gulp

I'm attempting to loop over objects within a key:value array in javascript in order to use the string.prototype.replace method against an array of paths to js files for GulpJS concat purposes.

The goal here is to pump out a list of paths that is usable by GULP but currently they need to be processed before doing so. To do this, I'm substituting the existing 'placeholder' value in the paths array with it's corresponding substitution value in the subs array and looping over until all the paths are literal.

The problem is that I want the console to return the paths that haven't been processed/fixed by the loop **i.e. '../test4'** (literal paths) so I can ignore them and do stuff with them once the loop is completed.

Here's what i have so far with some **test data** for demo purposes:

```js
function fixPaths(substitutionsArray, pathArray) {
    var fixedPaths = [];

    pathArray.forEach(function (path, index, array) {
        console.log('processing line ' + (index + 1) + '... ' + path);
        Object.keys(substitutionsArray).forEach(function (placeholder) {
                var substitution = substitutionsArray[placeholder];

                var fixPath = path.replace(placeholder, substitution);

                if (fixPath == path) {
                console.log('No replacement has been found in path ' + path + ' for placeholder ' + placeholder);

                } else {
                    console.log('Replacement found in path ' + path + ' for placeholder ' + placeholder + ' resulting in ' + fixPath);                    

                        fixedPaths.push(fixPath);
                }
            }
        )
    });
    console.log(fixedPaths);
    return fixedPaths;
}

var subs = {
    "@COMMON_JS@": "/test1",
    "@COMMON_ROOT@": "/test2",
    "@COMPONENT_ROOT@": "/test3",
    "@COMPONENT_WEB_ROOT@": "/components"
};
var paths = ['@COMMON_JS@/test1', '@COMMON_ROOT@/test2', '@COMPONENT_ROOT@/test3', '../test4', '../../test5'];

result = fixPaths(subs, paths);

console.log(result);

return;
```

Any suggestions on how best to achieve this?

Much appreciated - Ben

Answer (score 0):

The console cannot return the paths. Console.log always returns `undefined`...if you want, you can create a functions which returns the value you pass in and then log it, like so:

function log() {
  console.log.apply(console, arguments)
  return arguments
}

That will return the arguments you pass into it..you can read more about the arguments object here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments